# Skype on desktop doesn't recognize new sign-in details, but web app does

Tags: skype

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and my Skype version is 4.3.0. I created a new Skype account, and when I log in to the app, I get an error

> sorry, we didn't recognize your sign-in details

But I can successfully log in with web-based Skype.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Microsoft has stopped supporting Skype 4.3 now. It won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting a newer version of skype, v5 works fine.

> Important notice: All Skype for Linux clients version 4.3 and older will be retired on July 1, 2017. To keep chatting, please install the latest version of Skype for Linux.

From [skype](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)